# RDS ran out of space

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, performance, postgresql-performance

I moved a 2 25 GB databases to an RDS instance with 100 GB of SSD storage allocated.

However, I see that I only have 2 GB of space left!

What can cause this behaviour?

At first I thought logs, but there is no way you can have 50 GB of logs on a database that has less than 1 week of operation! or is it?

How can I free up space?

Comment: How are measuring the space consumed by data? Are you sure you're tables are vacuumed? (dead tuples take up space). Postgres gives you a ton of data in its stats tables. Analyze the db and check out where the space is being consumed